# Parsing text in BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am reading some product pages in python/BS4 and find an interesting variety in one line of code, the price of the item.

Sometimes the HTML is:

```
<span class="currency">$<span id="product_price">0.00</span></span>
```

And other times it will be:

```
<span class="currency">$17.95</span></b>
```

Using `price = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'currency'})`

I can isolate the span, but when I try to get just the text, using

```
priceStr = price.findAll(text=re.compile(r''))
```

and then write it to the output file with

```
divpage.write('Price = ' + str(priceStr) + '\n')
```

I get (for the first example):

```
Price = [u'$', u'0.00']
```

My question is, is there a way to read JUST the price, without the '$', and how do I translate the encoding from the "u'0.00'" to just "0.00"?

I know I can do this using the Python find & replace functions, but I'd like to stick to BSS4 as much as possible, without having to write w check for one form or the other...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use get_text() instead of find_all()

```
price_str = price.get_text() # $17.95
```

Then you can use lstrip to get rid of the dollar sign

```
price_str = price_str.lstrip('$') # 17.95
```

And you're done!

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex here can also help here, Keeping characters that you require and removing everything else.

```
if price_str is not None :
    price =  re.sub("[^0123456789.]","",price_str.get_text())
```